# Twilio Android outcoming call

Tags: android, twilio

I'm using the same code as `client.twilio.com.quickstart`

Trying to make outgoing call with Twilio.

Server gives me capability token so I'm successfully creating device and calling but having this error with no explanation: "Connection declined. Check the debugger for more information on the actual cause."

Could someone help me if it is client(Android) or Server issue.

Comment: Have you checked the debugger?

Comment: @philnash Debugger at Android yes - nothing useful.
Maybe there is one more debugger somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/debugger). Anything in there?